# Understanding setting a view

Tags: ios, swift

Fairly new to swift..

I have the following code in a viewController class:

```
var mapView: MKMapView!

override func loadView() {
    mapView = MKMapView()
    view = mapView

    let london = Capital(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275))
    let washington = Capital(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667))

    // works fine
    mapView.addAnnotation(london)
    // raises an error: Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'addAnnotation'
    view.addAnnotation(washington)
}
```

I am trying to understand why **mapView** has a different set of methods than **view**, even though we clearly state that **view = mapView**

Is **view** a special variable within a viewController class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not to do with what the `view` or the `mapView` IS but it is to do with how they are defined.

`MKMapView` is defined as a subclass of `UIView` therefore it is perfectly valid to say something like this...

`let foo: UIView = MKMapView()`

This will create a variable called `foo` that IS an `MKMapView` BUT you are telling the compiler that it is a `UIView` so the compiler will only let you run functions and access properties on `UIView`.

You could do something like this...

```
(foo as! MKMapView).addAnnotaion(...)
```

This will force the compiler to treat `foo` as an MKMapView. There are much safer ways of doing this too... (this will crash if it isn’t actually a MKMapView).

Safer way...

```
if let mapView = foo as? MKMapView {
    mapView.addAnnotation(...)
}
```

In your instance `view` is a property of UIviewController which is defined as UIView which is why you are getting your error.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens because of how you define variables in Swift. Since `mapView` is of the type `MKMapView` which inherits from a `UIView` (you can check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview)), it will have all the functions that `UIView` has plus whatever else was defined in the `MKMapView` class. `view` is able to hold `mapView` because of this inheritance, but thinks that it is only an `UIView` object. Since the `addAnnotation` function was only defined in the `MKMapView` class and not in `UIView`, `view` does not have access to this.

Answer (score 1):

`view` is a property of `UIViewController` whose type is `UIView`. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view)

`MKMapView` is a subclass of `UIView` and so you can assign it to the `view` property. Through inheritance, it has all of the properties and methods of a `UIView`(since it *is* a `UIView`) along with whatever else is specific to it, [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview).

Answer (score 1):

Each [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) has it's `UIView` instance that it manages. That `UIView` instance is stored in the `view` property of the `UIViewController` (excerpts from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view)):

> The view stored in this property represents the root view for the view controller's view hierarchy.

You are setting that `view` to the `mapView` to say that the current `viewController`'s `view` should be the `mapView` instance. By that the `viewController` from now on manages the `mapView` (e.g., taking care of setting a proper frame when the `viewController` is presented).

`mapView` is an instance of the `MKMapView` class. `MKMapView` subclasses `UIView`, so it inherits all the methods from `UIView`, however, it adds some more that are specialized for the presenting and handling the map.